# Prevent user from accessing a route depending on its type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I have an app running with React, Redux and Next.js. In my redux store I have a user which has, let's say, an attribute "type". Each type of users has its own array of "routes" it can access.

What is the best way to prevent the user from accessing certain routes ?
I am able to redirect with Next.js Middleware but I cannot manage to pass a variable to the request with the user's type.

Comment: Generally this is done with a "session" that's stored on the server some how, and identified by a securely-generated cookie. The server cannot trust the user identity from the request, but it can trust the cookie to identify an established session. From that, the trusted user id can be used to yes/no any particular route. Different frameworks do that in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the type as a parameter at the end of the URL. (See https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/). These parameters can be accessed in NextJS functions like getInitialProps and getServerSideProps, and also in the client-side using **next/router**.

Using such parameters, you can handle redirects and/or data-fetches according to the type.

Comment: But then the user can simply edit the URL.

Comment: Do you have your users stored in a database like firebase or something else?

Comment: That doesn't matter. If the user id or type is part of the request, then the client can trivially change "user" to "admin".

Comment: If the user exists in an online database, you can always verify whether what you received as a parameter is actually concurrent with the actual details of the user.

Comment: If this is not an option, I believe, you could use some sort of encoding for the parameters, like, an admin would be xyz123 and a superadmin() would be abc789